# How do I get the value of one row from a selected item in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF datagrid and I'm trying to get the value of my first row for the seleted item. I've tried using the following based on previous questions I've found here, but had no success:

```
var eventid = dataGridArchiveQueue.SelectedItem;
```

also tried:

```
var eventid = dataGridArchiveQueue.Columns[0].GetValue(dataGridArchiveQueue.SelectedItem);
```

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MVVM, you can bind an object in your view model to the datagrid's SelectedItem property as such;

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemInMyViewModel}" ... >
...
</DataGrid>
```

Then in your view model, you can expose this property with whatever type you like (meaning you won't need to cast it, but providing it is the type as the Array/List objects you are binding to the DataGrid's `ItemsSource`

For example if you were binding a List to the datagrid, on the view model you could have;

```
public Person SelectedItemInMyViewModel { get; set; }
```

You can then look at that property whenever you like to see the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedItem` is your row boxed to `object`, you need to [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) it back to the item type to access its members.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to C# and I don't understand how to do this. Could you please provide an example?